# VBS/Javascript URL Complex Application

Tags: javascript, html, search, vbscript

Okay so I'm very new to VBS and not so much Javascript but I have what i consider to be a complex question.

What im trying to do is create preferably a VBScript that can be used to load a URL and search for a phrase in either the pages text or source.

For example "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21Ox58OKFmo". I would like to know how i could create something that would replace the "v='21Ox58OKFmo'" with another number. Basically say that v = 55555 , i would want the program to add 1 to that 55555 and make it 55556 and reload the page and search for a word or piece of text. When it does discover that text, it returns back to me, telling me that it found that phrase.

> Something like this?
>
> > var numberChange = 55555
> >
> > load.URL(http://www.youtube.com/v="numberChange")'
> >
> > ///I understand that thats not in anyway how to code it but you get the point.
> >
> > ///then have something that searches for a phrase on that page.
> >
> > search.text("Hello");
> >     if text = 0 then numberChange+1
> >
> > ///The program loops again adding 1 to the variable each time till it finds the phrase >>"Hello" on the page.

I also need to make sure that it actually stops at a reasonable number so that my computer doesnt keep running the program.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
url    = "http://www.example.com/"
phrase = "..."

'load the page specified by the variable "url"
Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
req.open "GET", url, False
req.send

If req.status = 200 Then
  'if the page was successfully loaded, write the HTML to an HTMLFile object,
  'which will allow to retrieve the plain text (without HTML tags) from it
  Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
  html.Write req.responseText

  If InStr(html.body.innerText, phrase) > 0 Then
    'if the plain text contains the phrase do this
    WScript.Echo "Phrase found."
  Else
    'if the plain text doesn't contain the phrase do something else
    WScript.Echo "Phrase not found."
  End If
Else
  'if the page couldn't be loaded, show a message with status information
  WScript.Echo "Cannot load " & url & ": [" & req.status & "] " & req.statusText
End If
```

Comment: Okay this is a start but i am still a bit lost. So I changed the phrase to what i wanted and it found it no problem; however, I'm Lost after the phrase part and what everything does.

if it does not find the phrase what does it do? Is there a way so that it changes part of the url and then searches that page again?

Comment: @Monke I added some comments to explain what each step does. My original answer didn't do anything if the phrase wasn't found. I added a respective `Else` branch to the modified version. If you want to change the URL and retry if the phrase wasn't found, I'd recommend wrapping the code in a function that returns a boolean value depending on whether the phrase was found or not. Then you can modify the input to that function in a loop until it returns `True`.

Comment: Okay that helps a lot! Accept... I don't know how to do that... I'm pretty much clueless when it comes to this stuff, sorry! I hate to have you do everything but would you be able to write the skeleton of it and ill just fill in the values.

Comment: @Monke Sorry, but you *are* required to have at least a basic understanding of what you're doing. If you're looking for someone to do your work for you try something like [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.net/). SO is not the right place for that.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") for get web page. Samples available on this web site.
2. Use function "Pos" to find text in just download web page